# include dygraphs in latex

Tags: latex, dygraphs

I am using the dygraphs R package in order to obtain interactive time series plots. I am wondering if it would be possible to include the resulting plots in a Latex document while maintaining the interactivity.Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; LaTeX does not contain a JavaScript interpreter, which is required for dygraphs to work.